# How to change the activity to show the next page

Tags: android, android-activity

[image]I try to change page on android application. It have error but look like its swap a little while.

```
public class gps_gui extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}
public void onClick(View v){
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Already Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondPage.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

}


}
public class SecondPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_page);
}
```

}

In AndriodManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="gps.GUI"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".gps_gui"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="second_page"></activity>
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Anyone can help me ? thanks

Errors:
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {gps.GUI/gps.GUI.SecondPage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at gps.GUI.gps_gui$1.onClick(gps_gui.java:30)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-29 13:56:57.709: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created both activities in same files, please do it in a separate .java files and also declare the activity in an android manifest file with activity name.

---

**edited:**

---

It's because you have declared a different name in the java class and manifest file:

---

Use this in manifest file:

---

```
<activity android:name=".SecondPage"/>
```

Comment: and have you define activites in separate files?what error you r getting pls paste logcate in ur que also.

Comment: I did activities in separate files and add activity in AndroidManifest.

Comment: 01-29 13:53:23.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: this is short .i think more red lines would be tht.pste here

Comment: @Daisy. You declare activities in the Manifest with class name not layout name so you should change `<activity android:name="second_page"></activity>` to `<activity android:name="SecondPage"></activity>`. From the log, `Unable to find explicit activity class {gps.GUI/gps.GUI.SecondPage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot in your declaration of second Activity(common mistake)

```
<activity android:name=".second_page"></activity>
```

Assuming the first and second Activity are in the same package...